# VirtualBox over X Forwarding

Tags: ssh, freebsd, virtualbox, xforwarding

My local machine is Fedora laptop. My remote server is FreeBSD 11.0 (located across the room).

The objective is to have VirtualBox forwarded over SSH. If I plug a monitor into the remote server, run 'startx', and then 'VirtualBox', the VB manager shows up in a window with the VM I created via CLI.

I have configured both local and remote hosts to support X11 forwarding. I can run xclock and xcalc etc successfully from my laptop.

However, when I run 'VirtualBox' over SSH from the local machine to the remote, there is no output and the VB command just sits there, as if it has opened the VB manager on the remote machine and won't forward it the local display.

How can I get VirtualBox to forward its X session to my laptop?

Some outputs:

```
$ groups
user1 wheel operator vboxusers

$ export DISPLAY=VirtualBox
$ VirtualBox 
Qt FATAL: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display VirtualBox
Abort trap

$ export DISPLAY=localhost:10.0

$ ls -al /usr/local/lib/virtualbox/VirtualBox
-rwsr-xr-x  1 root  vboxusers  29568 May  2 03:36 /usr/local/lib/virtualbox/VirtualBox

$ truss -D -o VirtualBox.truss VirtualBox
VirtualBox: Error -10 in SUPR3HardenedMain!
VirtualBox: Effective UID is not root (euid=1000 egid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000)

VirtualBox: Tip! It may help to reinstall VirtualBox.

$ cat VirtualBox.truss 
0.000156317 mmap(0x0,32768,PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANON,-1,0x0) = 34366304256 (0x800643000)
0.000123821 issetugid()              = 0 (0x0)
0.000117001 lstat("/etc",{ mode=drwxr-xr-x ,inode=39,size=114,blksize=7680 }) = 0 (0x0)
0.000111085 lstat("/etc/libmap.conf",{ mode=-rw-r--r-- ,inode=716,size=109,blksize=4096 }) = 0 (0x0)
0.000049185 openat(AT_FDCWD,"/etc/libmap.conf",O_CLOEXEC,00) = 3 (0x3)
0.000037486 fstat(3,{ mode=-rw-r--r-- ,inode=716,size=109,blksize=4096 }) = 0 (0x0)
0.000036905 mmap(0x0,109,PROT_READ,MAP_PRIVATE,3,0x0) = 34366337024 (0x80064b000)
0.000021263 close(3)                 = 0 (0x0)
0.000025546 lstat("/usr",{ mode=drwxr-xr-x ,inode=9,size=16,blksize=4096 }) = 0 (0x0)
0.000025097 lstat("/usr/local",{ mode=drwxr-xr-x ,inode=1033,size=16,blksize=4096 }) = 0 (0x0)
0.000027033 lstat("/usr/local/etc",{ mode=drwxr-xr-x ,inode=16436,size=45,blksize=4096 }) = 0 (0x0)
0.000026056 lstat("/usr/local/etc/libmap.d",0x7fffffffcb48) ERR#2 'No such file or directory'
0.000024790 munmap(0x80064b000,109)      = 0 (0x0)
0.000033703 openat(AT_FDCWD,"/var/run/ld-elf.so.hints",O_CLOEXEC,00) = 3 (0x3)
0.000040055 read(3,"Ehnt\^A\0\0\0\M^@\0\0\0z\0\0\0\0"...,128) = 128 (0x80)
0.000019917 fstat(3,{ mode=-r--r--r-- ,inode=102408,size=250,blksize=4096 }) = 0 (0x0)
0.000018280 lseek(3,0x80,SEEK_SET)       = 128 (0x80)
0.000025942 read(3,"/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/lib/compat:/u"...,122) = 122 (0x7a)
0.000020733 close(3)                 = 0 (0x0)
0.000025979 access("/lib/libedit.so.7",F_OK)     = 0 (0x0)
0.000025470 openat(AT_FDCWD,"/lib/libedit.so.7",O_CLOEXEC|O_VERIFY,00) = 3 (0x3)
0.000019576 fstat(3,{ mode=-r--r--r-- ,inode=14363,size=226424,blksize=131072 }) = 0 (0x0)
0.000024346 mmap(0x0,4096,PROT_READ,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_PREFAULT_READ,3,0x0) = 34366337024 (0x80064b000)
0.000018860 mmap(0x0,2334720,PROT_NONE,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANON|MAP_NOCORE,-1,0x0) = 34368409600 (0x800845000)
0.000029369 mmap(0x800845000,212992,PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_NOCORE|MAP_PREFAULT_READ,3,0x0) = 34368409600 (0x800845000)
0.000026226 mmap(0x800a79000,8192,PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_PREFAULT_READ,3,0x34000) = 34370719744 (0x800a79000)
0.000019513 mmap(0x800a7b000,16384,PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANON,-1,0x0) = 34370727936 (0x800a7b000)
0.000019446 munmap(0x80064b000,4096)         = 0 (0x0)
0.000019183 close(3)                 = 0 (0x0)
0.000025349 access("/lib/libc.so.7",F_OK)    = 0 (0x0)
0.000025353 openat(AT_FDCWD,"/lib/libc.so.7",O_CLOEXEC|O_VERIFY,00) = 3 (0x3)
0.000019873 fstat(3,{ mode=-r--r--r-- ,inode=14386,size=1744304,blksize=131072 }) = 0 (0x0)
0.000023819 mmap(0x0,4096,PROT_READ,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_PREFAULT_READ,3,0x0) = 34366337024 (0x80064b000)
0.000018250 mmap(0x0,3883008,PROT_NONE,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANON|MAP_NOCORE,-1,0x0) = 34370744320 (0x800a7f000)
0.000095015 mmap(0x800a7f000,1634304,PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_NOCORE|MAP_PREFAULT_READ,3,0x0) = 34370744320 (0x800a7f000)
0.000027627 mmap(0x800e0d000,49152,PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_PREFAULT_READ,3,0x18e000) = 34374471680 (0x800e0d000)
0.000018430 mmap(0x800e19000,106496,PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANON,-1,0x0) = 34374520832 (0x800e19000)
0.000027453 munmap(0x80064b000,4096)         = 0 (0x0)
0.000018047 close(3)                 = 0 (0x0)
0.000024706 access("/lib/libncursesw.so.8",F_OK) = 0 (0x0)
0.000023619 openat(AT_FDCWD,"/lib/libncursesw.so.8",O_CLOEXEC|O_VERIFY,00) = 3 (0x3)
0.000017546 fstat(3,{ mode=-r--r--r-- ,inode=14357,size=375096,blksize=131072 }) = 0 (0x0)
0.000030595 mmap(0x0,4096,PROT_READ,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_PREFAULT_READ,3,0x0) = 34366337024 (0x80064b000)
0.000016633 mmap(0x0,2473984,PROT_NONE,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANON|MAP_NOCORE,-1,0x0) = 34374627328 (0x800e33000)
0.000042896 mmap(0x800e33000,356352,PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_NOCORE|MAP_PREFAULT_READ,3,0x0) = 34374627328 (0x800e33000)
0.000023676 mmap(0x801089000,20480,PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_PREFAULT_READ,3,0x56000) = 34377076736 (0x801089000)
0.000017803 mmap(0x80108e000,4096,PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANON,-1,0x0) = 34377097216 (0x80108e000)
0.000017629 munmap(0x80064b000,4096)         = 0 (0x0)
0.000018247 close(3)                 = 0 (0x0)
0.000020663 munmap(0x80064a000,4096)         = 0 (0x0)
0.000018793 mmap(0x0,40960,PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANON,-1,0x0) = 34366332928 (0x80064a000)
0.000017976 munmap(0x80064d000,28672)        = 0 (0x0)
0.000016795 mmap(0x0,102400,PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANON,-1,0x0) = 34366345216 (0x80064d000)
0.000016359 sysarch(AMD64_SET_FSBASE,0x7fffffffe518) = 0 (0x0)
0.000015639 sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK,{ SIGHUP|SIGINT|SIGQUIT|SIGKILL|SIGPIPE|SIGALRM|SIGTERM|SIGURG|SIGSTOP|SIGTSTP|SIGCONT|SIGCHLD|SIGTTIN|SIGTTOU|SIGIO|SIGXCPU|SIGXFSZ|SIGVTALRM|SIGPROF|SIGWINCH|SIGINFO|SIGUSR1|SIGUSR2 },{ }) = 0 (0x0)
0.000015775 sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK,{ },0x0)     = 0 (0x0)
0.000028953 readlink("/etc/malloc.conf",0x7fffffffdc10,1024) ERR#2 'No such file or directory'
0.000014833 issetugid()              = 0 (0x0)
0.000029755 __sysctl(0x7fffffffda80,0x2,0x7fffffffdad0,0x7fffffffdac8,0x800bde647,0xd) = 0 (0x0)
0.000017399 __sysctl(0x7fffffffdad0,0x2,0x7fffffffdb94,0x7fffffffdb88,0x0,0x0) = 0 (0x0)
0.000018493 mmap(0x0,2097152,PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANON,-1,0x0) = 34377101312 (0x80108f000)
0.000019866 munmap(0x80108f000,2097152)      = 0 (0x0)
0.000017340 mmap(0x0,4190208,PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANON,-1,0x0) = 34377101312 (0x80108f000)
0.000018613 munmap(0x80108f000,1511424)      = 0 (0x0)
0.000016699 munmap(0x801400000,581632)       = 0 (0x0)
0.000020123 sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK,{ SIGHUP|SIGINT|SIGQUIT|SIGKILL|SIGPIPE|SIGALRM|SIGTERM|SIGURG|SIGSTOP|SIGTSTP|SIGCONT|SIGCHLD|SIGTTIN|SIGTTOU|SIGIO|SIGXCPU|SIGXFSZ|SIGVTALRM|SIGPROF|SIGWINCH|SIGINFO|SIGUSR1|SIGUSR2 },{ }) = 0 (0x0)
0.000014259 sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK,{ },0x0)     = 0 (0x0)
0.000016319 sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK,{ SIGHUP|SIGINT|SIGQUIT|SIGKILL|SIGPIPE|SIGALRM|SIGTERM|SIGURG|SIGSTOP|SIGTSTP|SIGCONT|SIGCHLD|SIGTTIN|SIGTTOU|SIGIO|SIGXCPU|SIGXFSZ|SIGVTALRM|SIGPROF|SIGWINCH|SIGINFO|SIGUSR1|SIGUSR2 },{ }) = 0 (0x0)
0.000014869 sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK,{ },0x0)     = 0 (0x0)
0.000016173 sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK,{ SIGHUP|SIGINT|SIGQUIT|SIGKILL|SIGPIPE|SIGALRM|SIGTERM|SIGURG|SIGSTOP|SIGTSTP|SIGCONT|SIGCHLD|SIGTTIN|SIGTTOU|SIGIO|SIGXCPU|SIGXFSZ|SIGVTALRM|SIGPROF|SIGWINCH|SIGINFO|SIGUSR1|SIGUSR2 },{ }) = 0 (0x0)
0.000015156 sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK,{ },0x0)     = 0 (0x0)
0.000015643 sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK,{ SIGHUP|SIGINT|SIGQUIT|SIGKILL|SIGPIPE|SIGALRM|SIGTERM|SIGURG|SIGSTOP|SIGTSTP|SIGCONT|SIGCHLD|SIGTTIN|SIGTTOU|SIGIO|SIGXCPU|SIGXFSZ|SIGVTALRM|SIGPROF|SIGWINCH|SIGINFO|SIGUSR1|SIGUSR2 },{ }) = 0 (0x0)
0.000015386 sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK,{ },0x0)     = 0 (0x0)
0.000015033 getpid()                 = 4685 (0x124d)
0.000014269 geteuid()                = 1000 (0x3e8)
0.000015010 getppid()                = 4684 (0x124c)
0.000018670 mmap(0x0,2097152,PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANON,-1,0x0) = 34380709888 (0x801400000)
0.000014950 getuid()                 = 1000 (0x3e8)
0.000013960 geteuid()                = 1000 (0x3e8)
0.000014840 getgid()                 = 1000 (0x3e8)
0.000015257 getegid()                = 1000 (0x3e8)
0.000044759 openat(AT_FDCWD,"/usr/local/bin/VirtualBox",O_CLOEXEC,00) = 3 (0x3)
0.000015816 fcntl(3,F_DUPFD_CLOEXEC,0xa)     = 10 (0xa)
0.000016137 close(3)                 = 0 (0x0)
0.000015839 sigaction(SIGINT,0x0,{ SIG_DFL 0x0 ss_t }) = 0 (0x0)
0.000015793 sigaction(SIGINT,{ 0x41b950 0x0 ss_t },0x0) = 0 (0x0)
0.000015403 sigaction(SIGQUIT,0x0,{ SIG_DFL 0x0 ss_t }) = 0 (0x0)
0.000015320 sigaction(SIGQUIT,{ 0x41b950 0x0 ss_t },0x0) = 0 (0x0)
0.000014973 sigaction(SIGTERM,0x0,{ SIG_DFL 0x0 ss_t }) = 0 (0x0)
0.000017783 sigaction(SIGTERM,{ SIG_DFL 0x0 ss_t },0x0) = 0 (0x0)
0.000025106 stat(".",{ mode=drwxr-xr-x ,inode=8,size=22,blksize=4096 }) = 0 (0x0)
0.000036735 stat("/home/harry",{ mode=drwxr-xr-x ,inode=8,size=22,blksize=4096 }) = 0 (0x0)
0.000032722 read(10,"#!/bin/sh\n#\n# Oracle VM Virtua"...,1024) = 1024 (0x400)
0.000027649 stat("/usr/local/etc/vbox/vbox.cfg",0x7fffffffe6c0) ERR#2 'No such file or directory'
0.000028379 stat("/usr/local/lib/virtualbox",{ mode=drwxr-xr-x ,inode=61743,size=59,blksize=7680 }) = 0 (0x0)
0.000027360 stat("/usr/local/lib/virtualbox/VBoxRT.so",{ mode=-rw-r--r-- ,inode=102976,size=8236395,blksize=131072 }) = 0 (0x0)
0.000022672 read(10,"problem\nKDE_FORK_SLAVES=1; expo"...,1024) = 855 (0x357)
0.000027726 stat("/usr/bin/basename",{ mode=-r-xr-xr-x ,inode=2279,size=7520,blksize=7680 }) = 0 (0x0)
0.000022313 pipe2(0x7fffffffe4f8,O_RDONLY)   = 0 (0x0)
0.000039916 vfork()              = 4686 (0x124e)
0.000016393 close(4)                 = 0 (0x0)
0.000985596 read(3,"VirtualBox\n",128)       = 11 (0xb)
0.000015756 read(3,0x7fffffffe720,128)       = 0 (0x0)
0.000143777 close(3)                 = 0 (0x0)
0.000027776 wait4(-1,{ EXITED,val=0 },0x0,0x0)   = 4686 (0x124e)
0.000421038 execve("/usr/local/lib/virtualbox/VirtualBox",0x801418b70,0x801418c38) = 0 (0x0)
0.000017833 mmap(0x0,32768,PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANON,-1,0x0) = 34366181376 (0x800625000)
0.000014409 issetugid()              = 0 (0x0)
0.000020320 __sysctl(0x7fffffffe498,0x2,0x8008260bc,0x7fffffffe490,0x0,0x0) = 0 (0x0)
0.000029242 __sysctl(0x7fffffffe498,0x2,0x8008261bc,0x7fffffffe490,0x0,0x0) = 0 (0x0)
0.000018210 __sysctl(0x7fffffffe498,0x2,0x8008262bc,0x7fffffffe490,0x0,0x0) = 0 (0x0)
0.000018556 __sysctl(0x7fffffffe498,0x2,0x8008263bc,0x7fffffffe490,0x0,0x0) = 0 (0x0)
0.000018233 __sysctl(0x7fffffffe498,0x2,0x8008264bc,0x7fffffffe490,0x0,0x0) = 0 (0x0)
0.000028353 lstat("/etc",{ mode=drwxr-xr-x ,inode=39,size=114,blksize=7680 }) = 0 (0x0)
0.000024927 lstat("/etc/libmap.conf",{ mode=-rw-r--r-- ,inode=716,size=109,blksize=4096 }) = 0 (0x0)
0.000024313 openat(AT_FDCWD,"/etc/libmap.conf",O_CLOEXEC,00) = 3 (0x3)
0.000018616 fstat(3,{ mode=-rw-r--r-- ,inode=716,size=109,blksize=4096 }) = 0 (0x0)
0.000023359 mmap(0x0,109,PROT_READ,MAP_PRIVATE,3,0x0) = 34366214144 (0x80062d000)
0.000017803 close(3)                 = 0 (0x0)
0.000023113 lstat("/usr",{ mode=drwxr-xr-x ,inode=9,size=16,blksize=4096 }) = 0 (0x0)
0.000023040 lstat("/usr/local",{ mode=drwxr-xr-x ,inode=1033,size=16,blksize=4096 }) = 0 (0x0)
0.000024520 lstat("/usr/local/etc",{ mode=drwxr-xr-x ,inode=16436,size=45,blksize=4096 }) = 0 (0x0)
0.000024286 lstat("/usr/local/etc/libmap.d",0x7fffffffcb48) ERR#2 'No such file or directory'
0.000021119 munmap(0x80062d000,109)      = 0 (0x0)
0.000029960 access("/usr/local/lib/virtualbox/libthr.so.3",F_OK) ERR#2 'No such file or directory'
0.000027826 openat(AT_FDCWD,"/var/run/ld-elf.so.hints",O_CLOEXEC,00) = 3 (0x3)
0.000039259 read(3,"Ehnt\^A\0\0\0\M^@\0\0\0z\0\0\0\0"...,128) = 128 (0x80)
0.000018183 fstat(3,{ mode=-r--r--r-- ,inode=102408,size=250,blksize=4096 }) = 0 (0x0)
0.000016146 lseek(3,0x80,SEEK_SET)       = 128 (0x80)
0.000024223 read(3,"/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/lib/compat:/u"...,122) = 122 (0x7a)
0.000017516 close(3)                 = 0 (0x0)
0.000023163 access("/lib/libthr.so.3",F_OK)  = 0 (0x0)
0.000023303 openat(AT_FDCWD,"/lib/libthr.so.3",O_CLOEXEC|O_VERIFY,00) = 3 (0x3)
0.000018383 fstat(3,{ mode=-r--r--r-- ,inode=14345,size=118352,blksize=118784 }) = 0 (0x0)
0.000030429 mmap(0x0,4096,PROT_READ,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_PREFAULT_READ,3,0x0) = 34366214144 (0x80062d000)
0.000020577 mmap(0x0,2256896,PROT_NONE,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANON|MAP_NOCORE,-1,0x0) = 34368286720 (0x800827000)
0.000031709 mmap(0x800827000,110592,PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_NOCORE|MAP_PREFAULT_READ,3,0x0) = 34368286720 (0x800827000)
0.000023537 mmap(0x800a41000,8192,PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_PREFAULT_READ,3,0x1a000) = 34370490368 (0x800a41000)
0.000019107 mmap(0x800a43000,45056,PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANON,-1,0x0) = 34370498560 (0x800a43000)
0.000019839 munmap(0x80062d000,4096)         = 0 (0x0)
0.000018536 close(3)                 = 0 (0x0)
0.000028893 access("/usr/local/lib/virtualbox/libc++.so.1",F_OK) ERR#2 'No such file or directory'
0.000020823 access("/lib/libc++.so.1",F_OK)  ERR#2 'No such file or directory'
0.000023609 access("/usr/lib/libc++.so.1",F_OK)  = 0 (0x0)
0.000025740 openat(AT_FDCWD,"/usr/lib/libc++.so.1",O_CLOEXEC|O_VERIFY,00) = 3 (0x3)
0.000017964 fstat(3,{ mode=-r--r--r-- ,inode=13693,size=772424,blksize=131072 }) = 0 (0x0)
0.000039257 mmap(0x0,4096,PROT_READ,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_PREFAULT_READ,3,0x0) = 34366214144 (0x80062d000)
0.000017076 mmap(0x0,2879488,PROT_NONE,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANON|MAP_NOCORE,-1,0x0) = 34370543616 (0x800a4e000)
0.000040405 mmap(0x800a4e000,749568,PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_NOCORE|MAP_PREFAULT_READ,3,0x0) = 34370543616 (0x800a4e000)
0.000024907 mmap(0x800d04000,28672,PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_PREFAULT_READ,3,0xb6000) = 34373386240 (0x800d04000)
0.000018146 mmap(0x800d0b000,8192,PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANON,-1,0x0) = 34373414912 (0x800d0b000)
0.000018642 munmap(0x80062d000,4096)         = 0 (0x0)
0.000018309 close(3)                 = 0 (0x0)
0.000028199 access("/usr/local/lib/virtualbox/libcxxrt.so.1",F_OK) ERR#2 'No such file or directory'
0.000021446 access("/lib/libcxxrt.so.1",F_OK)    = 0 (0x0)
0.000023693 openat(AT_FDCWD,"/lib/libcxxrt.so.1",O_CLOEXEC|O_VERIFY,00) = 3 (0x3)
0.000018550 fstat(3,{ mode=-r--r--r-- ,inode=14339,size=107624,blksize=108032 }) = 0 (0x0)
0.000030643 mmap(0x0,4096,PROT_READ,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_PREFAULT_READ,3,0x0) = 34366214144 (0x80062d000)
0.000016633 mmap(0x0,2220032,PROT_NONE,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANON|MAP_NOCORE,-1,0x0) = 34373423104 (0x800d0d000)
0.000027810 mmap(0x800d0d000,102400,PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_NOCORE|MAP_PREFAULT_READ,3,0x0) = 34373423104 (0x800d0d000)
0.000023166 mmap(0x800f25000,8192,PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_PREFAULT_READ,3,0x18000) = 34375618560 (0x800f25000)
0.000018070 mmap(0x800f27000,16384,PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANON,-1,0x0) = 34375626752 (0x800f27000)
0.000018363 munmap(0x80062d000,4096)         = 0 (0x0)
0.000017536 close(3)                 = 0 (0x0)
0.000027806 access("/usr/local/lib/virtualbox/libm.so.5",F_OK) ERR#2 'No such file or directory'
0.000022143 access("/lib/libm.so.5",F_OK)    = 0 (0x0)
0.000023780 openat(AT_FDCWD,"/lib/libm.so.5",O_CLOEXEC|O_VERIFY,00) = 3 (0x3)
0.000019073 fstat(3,{ mode=-r--r--r-- ,inode=14388,size=192584,blksize=131072 }) = 0 (0x0)
0.000021970 mmap(0x0,4096,PROT_READ,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_PREFAULT_READ,3,0x0) = 34366214144 (0x80062d000)
0.000016562 mmap(0x0,2273280,PROT_NONE,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANON|MAP_NOCORE,-1,0x0) = 34375643136 (0x800f2b000)
0.000032510 mmap(0x800f2b000,172032,PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_NOCORE|MAP_PREFAULT_READ,3,0x0) = 34375643136 (0x800f2b000)
0.000022559 mmap(0x801155000,4096,PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_PREFAULT_READ,3,0x2a000) = 34377912320 (0x801155000)
0.000018713 munmap(0x80062d000,4096)         = 0 (0x0)
0.000017236 close(3)                 = 0 (0x0)
0.000027546 access("/usr/local/lib/virtualbox/libc.so.7",F_OK) ERR#2 'No such file or directory'
0.000020463 access("/lib/libc.so.7",F_OK)    = 0 (0x0)
0.000023396 openat(AT_FDCWD,"/lib/libc.so.7",O_CLOEXEC|O_VERIFY,00) = 3 (0x3)
0.000018830 fstat(3,{ mode=-r--r--r-- ,inode=14386,size=1744304,blksize=131072 }) = 0 (0x0)
0.000021924 mmap(0x0,4096,PROT_READ,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_PREFAULT_READ,3,0x0) = 34366214144 (0x80062d000)
0.000016646 mmap(0x0,3883008,PROT_NONE,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANON|MAP_NOCORE,-1,0x0) = 34377916416 (0x801156000)
0.000063045 mmap(0x801156000,1634304,PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_NOCORE|MAP_PREFAULT_READ,3,0x0) = 34377916416 (0x801156000)
0.000025247 mmap(0x8014e4000,49152,PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_PREFAULT_READ,3,0x18e000) = 34381643776 (0x8014e4000)
0.000020984 mmap(0x8014f0000,106496,PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANON,-1,0x0) = 34381692928 (0x8014f0000)
0.000020176 munmap(0x80062d000,4096)         = 0 (0x0)
0.000018226 close(3)                 = 0 (0x0)
0.000024149 access("/lib/libgcc_s.so.1",F_OK)    = 0 (0x0)
0.000024262 openat(AT_FDCWD,"/lib/libgcc_s.so.1",O_CLOEXEC|O_VERIFY,00) = 3 (0x3)
0.000019110 fstat(3,{ mode=-r--r--r-- ,inode=14369,size=56608,blksize=56832 }) = 0 (0x0)
0.000030196 mmap(0x0,4096,PROT_READ,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_PREFAULT_READ,3,0x0) = 34366214144 (0x80062d000)
0.000016836 mmap(0x0,2154496,PROT_NONE,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANON|MAP_NOCORE,-1,0x0) = 34381799424 (0x80150a000)
0.000024242 mmap(0x80150a000,57344,PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_NOCORE|MAP_PREFAULT_READ,3,0x0) = 34381799424 (0x80150a000)
0.000022563 mmap(0x801717000,4096,PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_PREFAULT_READ,3,0xd000) = 34383949824 (0x801717000)
0.000019697 munmap(0x80062d000,4096)         = 0 (0x0)
0.000017733 close(3)                 = 0 (0x0)
0.000017563 mmap(0x0,36864,PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANON,-1,0x0) = 34366214144 (0x80062d000)
0.000018923 munmap(0x800631000,20480)        = 0 (0x0)
0.000017069 mmap(0x0,69632,PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANON,-1,0x0) = 34366230528 (0x800631000)
0.000020306 munmap(0x80063b000,28672)        = 0 (0x0)
0.000017460 mmap(0x0,102400,PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANON,-1,0x0) = 34366271488 (0x80063b000)
0.000015196 sysarch(AMD64_SET_FSBASE,0x7fffffffe518) = 0 (0x0)
0.000016554 sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK,{ SIGHUP|SIGINT|SIGQUIT|SIGKILL|SIGPIPE|SIGALRM|SIGTERM|SIGURG|SIGSTOP|SIGTSTP|SIGCONT|SIGCHLD|SIGTTIN|SIGTTOU|SIGIO|SIGXCPU|SIGXFSZ|SIGVTALRM|SIGPROF|SIGWINCH|SIGINFO|SIGUSR1|SIGUSR2 },{ }) = 0 (0x0)
0.000015900 sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK,{ },0x0)     = 0 (0x0)
0.000027883 readlink("/etc/malloc.conf",0x7fffffffdc10,1024) ERR#2 'No such file or directory'
0.000014446 issetugid()              = 0 (0x0)
0.000022763 __sysctl(0x7fffffffda80,0x2,0x7fffffffdad0,0x7fffffffdac8,0x8012b5647,0xd) = 0 (0x0)
0.000016826 __sysctl(0x7fffffffdad0,0x2,0x7fffffffdb94,0x7fffffffdb88,0x0,0x0) = 0 (0x0)
0.000019066 mmap(0x0,2097152,PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANON,-1,0x0) = 34383953920 (0x801718000)
0.000019023 munmap(0x801718000,2097152)      = 0 (0x0)
0.000017503 mmap(0x0,4190208,PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANON,-1,0x0) = 34383953920 (0x801718000)
0.000022060 munmap(0x801718000,950272)       = 0 (0x0)
0.000017180 munmap(0x801a00000,1142784)      = 0 (0x0)
0.000016080 sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK,{ SIGHUP|SIGINT|SIGQUIT|SIGKILL|SIGPIPE|SIGALRM|SIGTERM|SIGURG|SIGSTOP|SIGTSTP|SIGCONT|SIGCHLD|SIGTTIN|SIGTTOU|SIGIO|SIGXCPU|SIGXFSZ|SIGVTALRM|SIGPROF|SIGWINCH|SIGINFO|SIGUSR1|SIGUSR2 },{ }) = 0 (0x0)
0.000016349 sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK,{ },0x0)     = 0 (0x0)
0.000015703 sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK,{ SIGHUP|SIGINT|SIGQUIT|SIGKILL|SIGPIPE|SIGALRM|SIGTERM|SIGURG|SIGSTOP|SIGTSTP|SIGCONT|SIGCHLD|SIGTTIN|SIGTTOU|SIGIO|SIGXCPU|SIGXFSZ|SIGVTALRM|SIGPROF|SIGWINCH|SIGINFO|SIGUSR1|SIGUSR2 },{ }) = 0 (0x0)
0.000016313 sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK,{ },0x0)     = 0 (0x0)
0.000016310 sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK,{ SIGHUP|SIGINT|SIGQUIT|SIGKILL|SIGPIPE|SIGALRM|SIGTERM|SIGURG|SIGSTOP|SIGTSTP|SIGCONT|SIGCHLD|SIGTTIN|SIGTTOU|SIGIO|SIGXCPU|SIGXFSZ|SIGVTALRM|SIGPROF|SIGWINCH|SIGINFO|SIGUSR1|SIGUSR2 },{ }) = 0 (0x0)
0.000015776 sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK,{ },0x0)     = 0 (0x0)
0.000016800 sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK,{ SIGHUP|SIGINT|SIGQUIT|SIGKILL|SIGPIPE|SIGALRM|SIGTERM|SIGURG|SIGSTOP|SIGTSTP|SIGCONT|SIGCHLD|SIGTTIN|SIGTTOU|SIGIO|SIGXCPU|SIGXFSZ|SIGVTALRM|SIGPROF|SIGWINCH|SIGINFO|SIGUSR1|SIGUSR2 },{ }) = 0 (0x0)
0.000015749 sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK,{ },0x0)     = 0 (0x0)
0.000022567 __sysctl(0x7fffffffda30,0x2,0x800a4dd50,0x7fffffffda38,0x0,0x0) = 0 (0x0)
0.000015837 getrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK,{ cur=536870912,max=536870912 }) = 0 (0x0)
0.000023257 __sysctl(0x7fffffffd930,0x2,0x7fffffffd980,0x7fffffffd978,0x80083dddc,0xd) = 0 (0x0)
0.000016669 __sysctl(0x7fffffffd980,0x3,0x800a4c370,0x7fffffffda38,0x0,0x0) = 0 (0x0)
0.000019444 mmap(0x0,2097152,PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANON,-1,0x0) = 34387001344 (0x801a00000)
0.000016130 thr_self(0x801a16000)        = 0 (0x0)
0.000016483 mmap(0x7fffdfffe000,4096,PROT_NONE,MAP_ANON,-1,0x0) = 140736951476224 (0x7fffdfffe000)
0.000016213 rtprio_thread(0x0,0x189a7,0x7fffffffda08) = 0 (0x0)
0.000015724 sysarch(AMD64_SET_FSBASE,0x7fffffffda08) = 0 (0x0)
0.000016133 sigaction(32,{ 0x800834d80 SA_SIGINFO ss_t },0x0) = 0 (0x0)
0.000015576 sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK,{ },0x0)     = 0 (0x0)
0.000017643 _umtx_op(0x7fffffffd9c8,UMTX_OP_WAKE,0x1,0x0,0x0) = 0 (0x0)
0.000018973 mprotect(0x0,0,PROT_NONE)        = 0 (0x0)
0.000014656 getpid()                 = 4685 (0x124d)
0.000014009 getpid()                 = 4685 (0x124d)
0.000016199 sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK,{ SIGHUP|SIGINT|SIGQUIT|SIGILL|SIGTRAP|SIGABRT|SIGEMT|SIGFPE|SIGKILL|SIGBUS|SIGSEGV|SIGSYS|SIGPIPE|SIGALRM|SIGTERM|SIGURG|SIGSTOP|SIGTSTP|SIGCONT|SIGCHLD|SIGTTIN|SIGTTOU|SIGIO|SIGXCPU|SIGXFSZ|SIGVTALRM|SIGPROF|SIGWINCH|SIGINFO|SIGUSR1|SIGUSR2 },{ }) = 0 (0x0)
0.000016419 sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK,{ },0x0)     = 0 (0x0)
0.000016913 getcontext(0x7fffffffd510)       = 0 (0x0)
0.000016353 sysarch(AMD64_GET_XFPUSTATE,0x7fffffffd4d8) = 0 (0x0)
0.000013756 getpid()                 = 4685 (0x124d)
0.000030570 __sysctl(0x7fffffffdaa0,0x4,0x607ad0,0x7fffffffda98,0x0,0x0) = 0 (0x0)
0.000014669 getuid()                 = 1000 (0x3e8)
0.000014203 getgid()                 = 1000 (0x3e8)
0.000013783 geteuid()                = 1000 (0x3e8)
0.000013069 geteuid()                = 1000 (0x3e8)
0.000017756 getegid()                = 1000 (0x3e8)
0.000025466 write(2,"VirtualBox",10)         = 10 (0xa)
0.000017090 write(2,": ",2)          = 2 (0x2)
0.000016617 write(2,"Error ",6)          = 6 (0x6)
0.000020069 write(2,"-",1)           = 1 (0x1)
0.000017273 write(2,"10",2)          = 2 (0x2)
0.000020110 write(2," in ",4)            = 4 (0x4)
0.000022583 write(2,"SUPR3HardenedMain",17)  = 17 (0x11)
0.000019926 write(2,"!\n",2)             = 2 (0x2)
0.000017810 write(2,"VirtualBox",10)         = 10 (0xa)
0.000017620 write(2,": ",2)          = 2 (0x2)
0.000019349 write(2,"Effective UID is not root (euid=",32) = 32 (0x20)
0.000018086 write(2,"1000",4)            = 4 (0x4)
0.000017833 write(2," egid=",6)          = 6 (0x6)
0.000019713 write(2,"1000",4)            = 4 (0x4)
0.000016940 write(2," uid=",5)           = 5 (0x5)
0.000018806 write(2,"1000",4)            = 4 (0x4)
0.000017313 write(2," gid=",5)           = 5 (0x5)
0.000018310 write(2,"1000",4)            = 4 (0x4)
0.000019312 write(2,")",1)           = 1 (0x1)
0.000017393 write(2,"\n",1)          = 1 (0x1)
0.000018970 write(2,"\n",1)          = 1 (0x1)
0.000021063 write(2,"VirtualBox",10)         = 10 (0xa)
0.000018726 write(2,": ",2)          = 2 (0x2)
0.000018260 write(2,"Tip! It may help to reinstall Vi"...,42) = 42 (0x2a)
0.000040303 setresgid(0x3e8,0x3e8,0x3e8)     = 0 (0x0)
0.000033389 setresuid(0x3e8,0x3e8,0x3e8)     = 0 (0x0)
0.000013507 getresuid(0x7fffffffc968,0x7fffffffc96c,0x7fffffffc964) = 0 (0x0)
0.000014017 getresgid(0x7fffffffc95c,0x7fffffffc960,0x7fffffffc958) = 0 (0x0)
0.000012170 sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK,{ SIGHUP|SIGINT|SIGQUIT|SIGILL|SIGTRAP|SIGABRT|SIGEMT|SIGFPE|SIGKILL|SIGBUS|SIGSEGV|SIGSYS|SIGPIPE|SIGALRM|SIGTERM|SIGURG|SIGSTOP|SIGTSTP|SIGCONT|SIGCHLD|SIGTTIN|SIGTTOU|SIGIO|SIGXCPU|SIGXFSZ|SIGVTALRM|SIGPROF|SIGWINCH|SIGINFO|SIGUSR1|SIGUSR2 },{ }) = 0 (0x0)
0.000292994 fork()               = 4687 (0x124f)
0.000018010 sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK,{ },0x0)     = 0 (0x0)
0.000279777 exit(0x1)               
0.000330862 process exit, rval = 1
```

Comment: VirtualBox has some limitations; some features are enabled by installing the Oracle VirtualBox Extension Pack.  However, other features still, e.g. nesting VirtualBox within VirtualBox, are not possible even with this extension pack installed.  You might want to consult the VirtualBox documentation on advanced use cases.  Also, make sure you have the Extension Pack installed.

Comment: How are you sshing in?  ssh -Y user@remote and then launching from a prompt works fine for me ...

Comment: ssh -Y doesn't work either. My DISPLAY env var after logging in is "localhost:11.0" ... I tried setting it to my laptop's IP, but then it gives a "Qt FATAL: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display"

Comment: I am using Virtualbox on a remote machine (I and it are running Ubuntu) and it works fine (but is really slow  -- I think slower than it should be). So if other applications are coming up fine (try a browser?) and VB isn't, that's surprising.

Comment: I would be for using `virt-manager`. It is opensource and has a great functionality of connecting to remote virtual machines over ssh out of the box.

Comment: @ILMostro_7 None of these limitations or the features in the extension pack are relevant to running the *manager*. Some of these may be relevant for graphical acceleration of VMs, but the scenario here isn't at that stage yet.

Comment: VirtualBox can't display on the remote machine if it isn't even running a display. What happens if you run `DISPLAY= VirtualBox` in the SSH session? If all else fails, try `truss -D -o VirtualBox.truss VirtualBox` and post the trace file.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I have added the truss output and a few other things to the post.

Comment: Have you looked at the [FreeBSD webpage, section 11.8](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/faq/book.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what works for me:

- Start ssh with `ssh -X user@1.2.3.4`.
- Note that $DISPLAY is 'localhost:10.0' or
  similar, and that's correct - it shouldn't be the guest's IP address.
- Start VirtualBox from the ssh prompt `virtualbox &`.

The VirtualBox gui appears on the guest, and vms started from it appear on the guest.

If this is already what you are doing, can you confirm that you don't start the VirtualBox gui on the host machine's display, or at least you close it? I don't think there is a way to move a windowed application from one X display to another.
Also, can you open browser windows or other apps more complex than xclock?